How to develop shared bottom tower serving different tasks
I have two model classes both pyramid architecture.

Let's say first task is predicting user will buy something with architecture [feature_embedding_128, dense_1048, dense_512, dense_128, dense_1]
Second task is predicting donating to charity at checkout with architecture [feature_embedding_64, dense_512, dense_256, dense_64, dense_1].

Let's say both these tasks are seperately optimized, with different learning rate, and learning rate scheduling. Now, let's say I want to merge these tasks:

We are adding much more feature embedding so we can not separate serve on both tasks, we will share these embeddings through a bottom tower to both and then serve tasks seperately in such an architecure:

bottom_embedding_1028, dense_512, dense_64 => output of these towers are concatanated with the bottom of two towers discussed above.


Now what is my problem is that basically I have 3 towers to optimize, (1) buy?, (2) charity?, (3) bottom shared embedding.
I have been struggling to how to systematically set up the learning rate. My model is just too big and I cannot do random/grid search coming up with learning rate for each tower.
Is there any paper out there discussing this? Any previous experience? I do apprecaite this.
